# Angular generate components in ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I have multiple components (more than 10) which slightly differ from each other, each of them make own request to API. I wonder how I can generate these components via `*ngFor` because now it looks like

```
<component1 *ngIf="activeTab === 0"></component1>
<component2 *ngIf="activeTab === 1"></component2>
<component3 *ngIf="activeTab === 2"></component3>
```

And this number is expected to grow. **Is there a way where I could make something like**

```
list = [
  {
    title: 'Component 1',
    component: Component1
  }
]

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.component}}</ng-container>
```

Comment: this would be helpful - https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

Comment: You need to look for, dynamically generated components. I have used if for modals where my modal content where different. I had referred "https://github.com/ankosoftware/ng2-bootstrap-modal" though its quite old you but you can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done via `ngComponentOutlet` directive which accepts a `Type<any>` (a type of any component) as its input and can also accept inputs and many more. For details please refer to [the documentation](https://angular.dev/api/common/NgComponentOutlet?tab=usage-notes).

With new control flow syntax it would look the following way.

```html
@for (item of list; track item) {
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item.component" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use smart component that can be useful for your problem

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/